# Javascript Treeview, Array inside Array

Tags: javascript

I am working on a treeview and I created a class Node, consisting of a name and a list of children.

```
class Node {
  constructor(name, childNodes) {
    this.name = name;
    this.childNodes = childNodes;
  }
}
```

I am trying to create an object looking like the object "tree" in the image below. Every Node has a attribute called "nodes" which is the childNode-Array.
I got very close to creating the same tree, but in my version there is an extra "Array"-Layer around each of the Child nodes (see the recTreeview()-Element):

[image]

I am not sure how to fix this problem. The array has to be created to contain the childnodes. Here is the code where the treeview Element is created:

```
function recTreeview(currentNode, treeview) {
  var tempChildren = [];
  currentNode.children.forEach(child => {
    tempChildren.push(recTreeview(child, []));
  });
  treeview.push({
    text: currentNode.name,
    nodes: tempChildren
  });

  return treeview;
}
```

Is there anything I can do? Update: A Code-Snippet:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(name, children) {
    this.children = children;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

function recTreeview(currentNode, treeview) {
  var tempChildren = [];
  currentNode.children.forEach(child => {
    tempChildren.push(recTreeview(child, []));
  });
  treeview.push({
    text: currentNode.name,
    nodes: tempChildren
  });

  return treeview;
}

child1 = new Node("child1", []);
child2 = new Node("child2", []);
parent = new Node("Parent", [child1, child2]);

var tree = [
  {
      text: "Parent 1",
      nodes: [
          {
              text: "Child 1"
          },
          {
              text: "Child 2"
          }
      ]
  }
];
```

```html
<button onClick="console.log(recTreeview(parent, []));">Wrong</button>
<button onClick="console.log(tree);">Right</button>
```

Comment: so you want to filter all the arrays then create a child with those items inside then rinse and repeat till all items are handled

Comment: I'm afraid the code is too fragmentary for us to help you with such a specific problem. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: The extra array is comming from `tempChildren.push(recTreeview(child, []));`. Because you are pushing the return value of `recTreeview` (which is an array) to the children array `tempChildren`. I can't post an answer because I don't know what `recTreeview` is supposed to do and how to change the code

Comment: @Ibrahimmahrir Yes, thats exactly the problem. I just want it to be 1 array instead of an array inside an array. I added a runnable Code Snippet

Comment: what is `recTreeview` doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra array is comming from `tempChildren.push(recTreeview(child, []));`. Because you are pushing the return value of `recTreeview` (which is an array) to the children array `tempChildren`.

Instead of pushing the new array to `tempChildren`, you should pass `tempChildren` as the parameter to `recTreeview`:

```
currentNode.children.forEach(child => {
    recTreeview(child, tempChildren);
});
```

So that the children will be pushed directly to the `tempChildren` array instead of getting wrapped in the extra array `recTreeview` is creating.

**Example:**

```js
class Node {
  constructor(name, children) {
    this.children = children;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

function recTreeview(currentNode, treeview) {
  var tempChildren = [];
  currentNode.children.forEach(child => {
    recTreeview(child, tempChildren);
  });
  treeview.push({
    text: currentNode.name,
    nodes: tempChildren
  });

  return treeview;
}

child1 = new Node("child1", []);
child2 = new Node("child2", []);
parent = new Node("Parent", [child1, child2]);

var tree = [
  {
      text: "Parent 1",
      nodes: [
          {
              text: "Child 1"
          },
          {
              text: "Child 2"
          }
      ]
  }
];
```

```html
<button onClick="console.log(recTreeview(parent, []));">Not Wrong Anymore</button>
<button onClick="console.log(tree);">Right</button>
```

**Note:**

If you want to get rid of that empty `nodes` array if there are no children, then change this:

```
treeview.push({
    text: currentNode.name,
    nodes: tempChildren
});
```

To:

```
var node = {
    text: currentNode.name
};
if(tempChildren.length) {
    node.nodes = tempChildren;
}
treeview.push(node);
```

Which only adds the `nodes` property if the `tempChildren` array is not empty.

Comment: Thanks! That totally makes sense, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @Basti I've added a **note** regarding that empty `nodes` array. Check it out!